# Terraform resource_aws_vpc_endpoint Dns list empty

Tags: terraform, amazon-vpc, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using terraform 0.12 and trying to setup a vpc endpoint to another VPC.  When I try to setup the alias route 53 record I always receive and error indicating the dns_entry is an empty list.  Am I missing something obvious here. If I re-execute apply afterwards, it will populate the DNS entry without issue.

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "endpoint" {
  vpc_id            = "${local.vpc_id}"
  service_name      = "${var.service_endpoint}"
  vpc_endpoint_type = "Interface"
  security_group_ids = [
    "${aws_security_group.privatelink.id}",
  ]
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint_subnet_association" "tk-subnet-assc" {
  count           = (var.endpoint_subnet_count)
  vpc_endpoint_id = "${aws_vpc_endpoint.endpoint.id}"
  subnet_id       = "${local.vpc_private_subnets[count.index]}"
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "hz" {
  name          = "${var.privatelink_dns_zone}"
  force_destroy = true
  vpc {
    vpc_id = "${local.vpc_id}"
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "tk" {
  zone_id = "${aws_route53_zone.hz.zone_id}"
  name    = "${var.privatelink_dns_name}.${var.privatelink_dns_zone}"
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = ["${lookup(aws_vpc_endpoint.endpoint.dns_entry[0], "dns_name")}"]
}
```

Error: Invalid index

```
 on main.tf line 55, in resource "aws_route53_record" "tk":
  55:   records = ["${lookup(aws_vpc_endpoint.endpoint.dns_entry[0], "dns_name")}"]
    |----------------
    | aws_vpc_endpoint.endpoint.dns_entry is empty list of object

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the error?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Yes meant to include it

Comment: This would be easier to answer if your example was a bit more complete. It might be worth reading the [mcve] page about what counts as a good example to use in your question.

Comment: Is the `aws_vpc_endpoint.endpoint.id` also empty on your first `apply`?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR This is the complete example, that sets this up.

Comment: @MattSchuchard No Id has a value as the aws_vpc_endpoint_subnet_association's work the first time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking closer at the AWS terraform provider I figured it out. When the read is done via the API it is done as soon as the endpoint is created, because I chose to create the subnet associations after the endpoint, the endpoint read doesn't include those and never gets re-read. To solve this add the subnet_ids directly to the endpoint. Example below:

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "endpoint" {
  vpc_id            = "${local.vpc_id}"
  service_name      = "${var.service_endpoint}"
  vpc_endpoint_type = "Interface"
  security_group_ids = [
    "${aws_security_group.privatelink.id}",
  ]
  subnet_ids = ["${local.vpc_private_subnets[0]}", "${local.vpc_private_subnets[1]}"]
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "hz" {
  name          = "${var.privatelink_dns_zone}"
  force_destroy = true
  vpc {
    vpc_id = "${local.vpc_id}"
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "tk" {
  zone_id = "${aws_route53_zone.hz.zone_id}"
  name    = "${var.privatelink_dns_name}.${var.privatelink_dns_zone}"
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = ["${lookup(aws_vpc_endpoint.endpoint.dns_entry[0], "dns_name")}"]
}
```

Comment: Check your Terraform logs but I suspect what was happening here is that Terraform infers a dependency between the endpoint and the subnet association and the endpoint and the route 53 record (because they both reference the endpoint) but NOT between the subnet association and the route 53 record (because neither references the other). So potentially Terraform was creating the route 53 record *before* it created the subnet association. Another way to work around this would have been to explicitly use `depends_on` in the route 53 record to ensure it was created *after* the subnet association.

Comment: @Nathan, I did go that route and it is created correctly without depends on, see my answer above as to when the read of the resource is done.

Comment: I see what you're saying, so the state of the endpoint in Terraform isn't getting updated with the subnet dns details after you make the association. Maybe an alternative might have been to declare a data resource for the endpoint and use that to populate the records for th route 53 record, but your solution to pass the subnets directly in the endpoint resource is the cleanest way to do it.